# Autenticação jwt com vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jwt, axios, vue-router

Estou um pouco confuso com a autenticação utilizando token jwt, tenho uma aplicação em vuejs + vue-router, não estou querendo utilizar vuex enquanto não aprender a fazer sem ele(não gosto de usar o que não entendo). Então tenho minha API em NodeJS que me concede um payload com token quando o usuário faz o login.

Minha dúvida é, agora tenho esse token, o que faço com ele? li vários artigos, disseram para armazenar no local storage(vulnerável a XSS), outros no cookie(vulnerável a CSRF), mas não quero entrar muito em segurança aqui, pois ainda nem fiz funcionar de nenhuma maneira. O que fiz foi armazenar no local storage quando recebo a resposta com o token do servidor assim.

no meu **main.js** está assim:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000'
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = "Bearer" + localStorage.getItem('jwtToken')

Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.meta.requiresAuth) {
        if (**O QUE COLOCO AQUI SEM UTILIZAR O VUEX?**) {
            next() 
        } else {
            next('/')
        }
    } else {
        next()
    }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  axios,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

Onde "to.meta.requiresAuth" quer dizer: as rotas que possuírem o elemento "meta.requiresAuth = true" serão interceptadas pela lógica dentro do if.

Podem ver que não sei que verificação fazer, na verdade poderia até verificar a existência ou não do token no local storage, mas acredito que apenas verificar a existência ou não, seria bem inseguro. Já que poderia dizer que possui o token sendo que ainda não foi recebido pelo servidor. Mas caso eu faça isso, a maneira que pensei seria enviar um post para o servidor e validar o token, se for válido, então next(), se não é redirecionado para a home. Porém não sei se é a maneira adequada de lidar com esse problema. Estou meio perdido.

Comment: Cara acho que ambos meios de autenticação irão possuir problemas de autenticação, mas geralmente, ainda mais no Vuejs eu costumo salvar o token jwt no localStorage mesmo e crio um interceptor do axios que verifica em cada request, se o token está válido, e não faço essa verificação na rota em si. Nas rotas geralmente deixo para tratar apenas se ele possui o token no localStorage ou não. Se desejar posso fazer uma resposta com explicação e o código disto que estou falando. Estou comentando pois não é exatamente o que você quer pelo que eu entendi.

Comment: É pelo que vi aqui, seria isso mesmo, nas rotas no cliente liberar apenas se o token existir,  e quando precisar requisitar algo na api do backend, então validar o token, caso não seja valido, enviar o 401, para assim no cliente redirecionar para home. Seria uma boa fazer uma resposta para a pergunta, se tiver com tempo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No caso, como disse nos comentários, eu geralmente salvo o token do JWT no localStorage. Primeiramente sobre o bloqueio de rotas, eu costumo bloquear toda e qualquer requisição criando um `interceptor` no axios.
Para isto, pode-se criar um arquivo js como, por exemplo um `http.js` que faz esse controle de requisições e intercepta-as verificando se o usuário possui um token válido ou não, que por fim exportará uma instância do axios. Segue abaixo:

**http.js**

```
import axios from 'axios'

let api = 'http://localhost:8080/api/'

const http = axios.create({
  baseURL: api
})

http.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('user-token')

  if (token) {
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`
  }

  return config
}, (err) => {
  return Promise.reject(err)
})

http.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
  return response
}, (error) => {
  if (error.response.status === 401) {
    window.location = '#/home'
  }

  return Promise.reject(error)
})

export default http
```

Basicamente em cada requisição, ele irá passa pelo método `interceptors.request` e verificar se possui o token previamente, e caso contrário voltará um erro diretamente, sem chegar ao back-end de fato. O mesmo irá ocorrer no caso da resposta, e como você disse caso não seja válido (401), o usuário é redirecionado para a home. Para utilizá-lo, pode ser importado de forma global em seu `main.js` ou por componente.

Falando sobre travar diretamente nas rotas da sua aplicação, ou seja, ao passar pelo seu `router`, usualmente eu faço de duas formas:

**Para travar apenas uma rota:**

```
routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      beforeEnter: function (to, from, next) {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('user-token')

        if (!token) {
          next('/login')
        } else {
          next()
        }
      },
      component: require('@/components/Home').default
    },
  ]
```

Neste caso ele está verificando o token antes de entrar na rota, e caso não exista, o usuário é redirecionado para o login.

**Para travar todas as rotas**

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('user-token')

  if (!token) {    
    next('/login')
    return;
  }

  next();
});
```

Mesmo funcionamento, porém irá verificar em todas as rotas, e se o token não existir, irá redirecionar para o login. Neste caso deve ter uma constante routes obrigatoriamente, com todas suas rotas dentro.

```
const router = new Router({
  routes: []
});
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Só mais uma dúvida, e como você implementa o compartilhamento desse estado de logado ou não logado entre os componentes?

Comment: Então, para isto em minha opinião a melhor maneira é utilizando o Vuex mesmo, onde ao logar você irá disparar uma action para uma Store de Login ou Usuário, onde nela fará a requisição de autenticação. Com a resposta, irá acionar uma mutation que por sua vez, salvará em um state. Utilizando o mapState em cada componente, uma propriedade computada, você terá acesso ao usuário logado. Não comentei nada pois você não queria usar o Vuex rs.

Comment: sim, mas acabei lendo a doc dele e utilizando kkkk porém percebi um problema, se atualizo a página o vuex reinicia os valores do "state", como você contorna isso? Estou contornando assim no meu main.js: `if (localStorage.getItem('jwtToken')) {
     store.commit('setIsLogged', true)
}`

Comment: Sim, sempre que atualizar você perde os dados. Eu estruturo minha aplicação para no primeiro componente que for criado ("pai"), o que possuir o `router-view` da aplicação toda, eu coloc para fazer a requisição dos dados do usuário logado no `created()`, assim toda vez que ocorrer o F5 (atualização da tela), sempre fará primeiro a requisição, e todos os componentes que serão sempre chamados depois dele, possuindo os dados logado. O localStorage não precisa estar dentro da Store também necessariamente, e ele não se perde na atualização da tela.